# Вызов экшн-метода по нажатию Radio button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть, к примеру 3 radio buttons. Я хочу, чтобы по нажатию
на них вызывался экшн-метод нужный из контроллера.
Я не знаю, как это сделать через JQuery. Или есть другие варианты ?

```
       <h3>Пол:</h3>

        @Html.RadioButton("Gender", "All", true, new {id = "radioAll"})
        @Html.Label("Все")

    <br/>

        @Html.RadioButton("Gender", "Male", false, new {id = "radioMale"})
        @Html.Label("Мужской")

    <br/>
    @Html.RadioButton("Gender", "Female", false, new {id = "radioFemale"})
    @Html.Label("Женский")

    // я пытался пользоваться разными вариантами, но зашёл в тупик.
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = '@Url.Action("ShowUsers", "Home")';

        if ($("#radioMale").attr("checked") === "checked") {
            $.post(url, 'choice=' + "Male");
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Делается следующим образом:

```
if ($('#radioMale').prop('checked')) { // bool - значение (true-если выбрано, false-если нет)
   ...
}
```